# 2 column layout with flexBox on React Native

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I'm trying to do a two column layout in React Native from a list of items. It only seems to work if I define the width of the items, I would like to define just a percentage of the parent width (0.5 would make a 2 column layout, but 0.25 would make a 4 column one). Can this be done?

```js
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={[styles.container, {width:width}]}>
        <View style={styles.item}><Text>{'item1'}</Text></View>
        <View style={styles.item}><Text>{'item2'}</Text></View>
        <View style={styles.item}><Text>{'item3'}</Text></View>
        <View style={styles.item}><Text>{'item4'}</Text></View>
        <View style={styles.item}><Text>{'item4'}</Text></View>
        <View style={styles.item}><Text>{'item5'}</Text></View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  item :{
    flex: 0.5, //why this doesnt work???
    // width: 150, //using fixed item width instead of flex: 0.5 works
    height: 100,
    padding: 10,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    // flexGrow: 1,
    // flexShrink: 0,
  }
});
```

You can play with it here: https://snack.expo.io/SyBjQuRxm

Css working equivalent: https://codepen.io/klamping/pen/WvvgBX?editors=110

Obviously I could do something like creating a container for each column, but that's not the point:

```js
render() {
    return (
      <View style={[styles.container, {width:width}]}>
        <View style={styles.column1}>
             <View style={styles.item}><Text>{'item1'}</Text></View>
             <View style={styles.item}><Text>{'item2'}</Text></View>
             <View style={styles.item}><Text>{'item3'}</Text></View>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.column2}>
             <View style={styles.item}><Text>{'item4'}</Text></View>
             <View style={styles.item}><Text>{'item4'}</Text></View>
             <View style={styles.item}><Text>{'item5'}</Text></View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Would you mind updating those links? They don't work anymore, thank you!

Answer (score 137, accepted):

It is possible if you use percentage values for the widths:

```js
<View style={styles.container}>
  <View style={styles.item}>
    ...
  </View>
</View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    alignItems: 'flex-start' // if you want to fill rows left to right
  },
  item: {
    width: '50%' // is 50% of container width
  }
})
```

Comment: Works perfectly, somehow I totally forgot about the width percentage. Thanks!

Comment: If you had to add spacing between each column item, how would one do that? (without using absolute padding or margins)

Comment: @jaimish11 to achieve that, you can try setting justifyContent: 'space-between' on the container, and reduce the item width to say, 48% instead of 50%.

Answer (score 6):

you can try scrollview with flatlist. the code below generates 2 columns. if you want 3 columns change numcolumn={data.length/3} etc.

```
             <ScrollView
              horizontal
              showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
              showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
              contentContainerStyle={{
                flexDirection: 'row',
                flexWrap: 'wrap',
              }}>
              <FlatList
                data={data}
                renderItem={this.renderItem}
                keyExtractor={item => `${item.id}`}
                showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                numColumns={data.length / 2}
              />
            </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could map the list of element into a an array of pairs.

Then render the pairs as a row inside a list

```
     <View className="px-4 ">
        {Buttons.map((row, i) => {
          return (
            <View className="flex-1 flex-row" key={i}>
              {row.map((item, j) => {
                return <ThumbButton key={j} {...item} />;
              })}
            </View>
          );
        })}
      </View>
```

For making the nested array you could use this function https://stackoverflow.com/a/44937519/1807666

```
function combineTwo(inputArray: Array<object>) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i += 2) {    
    result.push([inputArray[i], inputArray[i + 1]]); 
  }
  return result;
}'''
```

Comment: this isn't in React Native, but I found doing this method with list of rows easier than the accepted percentage width answer. Also can be easily done with `_.chunk(array, 2)` using lodash https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#chunk